# Implementing an algorithm with repeat/until using Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Help me simulate this algorithm:
[image]

Given the array [5 3 1 9 8 2 4 7], assume that l = 0.

I converted it to code:

```
public class Test {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {5,3,1,9,8,2,4,7};
    int l = 0;
    int p = a[l];

    int i=l;

    int j = 8;
    do{
        do{
            i++;
            System.out.println("Value of i " + i);

        }while(a[i]>=p);
        do{
            j--;
            System.out.println("\nValue of j " + j);

        }while(a[j]<p);
        swap(a,i,j);
        System.out.println("\nSwapped! a[i] = " + a[i] + " a[j] = " + a[j]);
        System.out.println("Swap 1");
        for(int k : a){
            System.out.print(k + " ");

        }

    }while(i>=j);
    if(i>=j){
        swap(a,i,j);
        System.out.println("\nSwapped! a[i] = " + a[i] + " a[j] = " + a[j]);
        System.out.println("Swap 2");
        for(int k : a){
            System.out.print(k + " ");

        }
    }
    else{
        swap(a,i,j);
        System.out.println("\nSwapped! a[i] = " + a[i] + " a[j] = " + a[j]);
        System.out.println("Swap 3");
        for(int k : a){
            System.out.print(k + " ");

        }
        swap(a,l,j);
        System.out.println("\nSwapped! a[l] = " + a[l] + " a[j] = " + a[j]);
        System.out.println("Swap 4");
        for(int k : a){
            System.out.print(k + " ");

        }

    }


    System.out.println("\nreturn value is: " + j);

    System.out.println("Final array: ");
    for(int k : a){
        System.out.print(k + " ");
    }

}

public static  void swap(int a[], int a1, int a2){
    int temp = a[a1];
    a[a1] = a[a2];
    a[a2] = temp;
}

}
```

The result is:

[image]

But when I simulate it in paper, my results are different. It's either I mistook "repeat until" with "do while" or I wrongly analyzed in paper.

Share me your simulations mates :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's either I mistaken `repeat` `until` for `do` `while` or I wrongly analyzed in paper.

You did translate `repeat`/`until` incorrectly.

[The construct comes from Pascal-like languages.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_repeat_until_loop.htm) It is similar to `do`/`while`, but the meaning of the condition is completely opposite: in `do`/`while` the condition at the end is *continuation condition*, but in `repeat`/`until` the condition is the *termination condition*.

The fix for this problem is inverting the conditions of `repeat`/`until` loops:

```
do{
    i++;
    System.out.println("Value of i " + i);
} while(a[i]< p);
//          ^
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now I the same results as on my simulation on paper. A big thanks for your clarification! :)